# requests[python lib] doesn't get correct response with post

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I want to communicate with some website. I successfully login into the site but I can't send  query below. parameter is clear in below images but I don't know why my code response code 400.

Header:
[image: Headers]

Params:
[image: params]

Here is my code in python:

```
#init user-agent header for perfomance and compatibility
heads={ 'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0" }
user = "XXXXXXXXXXX"
user_id="4013370545"

#update session
user_url = instagram_url + user + "/"
result=c.get(user_url,headers=heads)

#fist request for followers.
qdata= "ig_user("+user_id+")+{++followed_by.first(10)+{++++count,++++page_info+{++++++end_cursor,++++++has_next_page++++},++++nodes+{++++++id,++++++is_verified,++++++followed_by_viewer,++++++requested_by_viewer,++++++full_name,++++++profile_pic_url,++++++username++++}++}}"
queryid="17851938028087704"
query_data=dict(q=qdata,ref="relationships::follow_list",query_id=queryid)
query_data= {'q': qdata, 'ref': "relationships::follow_list", 'query_id': queryid}
#query_data="q="+qdata+"ref="+"relationships::follow_list"+"query_id="+queryid

#set number of header required for login
heads['X-Requested-With']="XMLHttpRequest"
heads['X-Instagram-AJAX']="1"
heads['Referer']='https://www.instagram.com/'+user+'/'
heads['Host']= 'www.instagram.com'
heads['X-CSRFToken']=result.cookies['csrftoken']
#heads['Accept-Encoding']="gzip, deflate, br"
#heads['Accept-Language']="en-US,en;q=0.5"
#heads['Accept']='*/*'
#heads['Content-Type']='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

#login to the instagram using query_data and prepared headers
result =c.post(instagram_url+"query/", data=query_data, headers=heads)
```

but result is:

```
<Response [400]>
```

where is my mistake? any suggestion?

Comment: If you're querying Instagram, why don't you use their comprehensive and well-documented API?

Comment: I have own reasons. But the most important is very restrict limitation of Instagram.

Comment: Two things. First: A "400" status code means your request was "bad" in that it doesn't jive with what they expect you to be doing, you'll likely want to read up on their API documentation. Two: They are very restrictive of their usage for a reason, they may outright ban you if you violate their rules.

Comment: I know 400 means bad request. But I can't find reason for that...

Comment: Because they have presumably spent a lot of effort preventing you doing exactly what you are trying to do. Use the API.

Comment: Hmmm... intersting...